# While running, i get this in my android monitor, it keeps expanding with no ends :

Tags: flutter, api, dart, caching

2
D/EGL_emulation( 4344): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa7b05720: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa7b03800)
2
D/EGL_emulation( 4344): eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf80cf60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x93bdd830)
D/EGL_emulation( 4344): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa7b05720: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa7b03800)
I/zygote  ( 4344): Do partial code cache collection, code=61KB, data=51KB
I/zygote  ( 4344): After code cache collection, code=61KB, data=51KB
I/zygote  ( 4344): Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB

Comment: Please provide what device you are using. Physical or Emulator ?